# How's my proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

**Prove that not every boolean function is equal to a boolean function constructed by only using $∧$ and $∨$.**

If p,q = (0,1)

(p$∧$q)$∨$q = (0$∧$1)$∨$1 = 1

(p$∧$q)$∨$~q = (0$∧$1)$∨$~1 = 0

Therefore (p$∧$q)$∨$q $≠$ (p$∧$q)$∨$~q.

Is my proof good enough? I realize that this question has been asked more than once here but I didn't quite understand the proofs that they gave. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: No, it is not. You really have not proved anything related to the question.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo thanks. Which basically means I don't understand the question. If you're willing can you please explain to me what it is asking me to do?

Comment: You need to give an example of a Boolean function $f$ with the property that $f\ne g$ for *all* Boolean functions $g$ constructed using only $\land$ and $\lor$.

Comment: You could represent the function f such that f(x)=x using $\land$ and $\lor$ by using [x$\land$(x$\lor$y)].  There's a Boolean function "**1**" such that **1** (x, y)=1 for all x, y, which can represent every tautology.  Can you make any tautologies using *just* $\land$ and $\lor$ and variables?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's good enough because you are just showing that two particular boolean functions are not always equal.  Hint: use a single variable, two is unnecessarily complicated.